# Generic Method Constraint error - Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, dependency-injection

I have this method:

```
public T GetRepositoryByType<T>() where T : IContextDependent
{
    var instance = this.Repositories.SingleOrDefault(x => x is T);

    return (T)instance;
}
```

Which needs to be able to return any repository instance, that implements `IContextDependent`, so I can set the DbContext for each manually.

When I build I get this error:

> Error CS0425  The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method
>   'RepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryByType()' must match the
>   constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method
>   'IRepositoryProvider.GetRepositoryByType()'. Consider using an
>   explicit interface implementation instead.

However, if I consider this code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx):

```
void SwapIfGreater<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs) where T : System.IComparable<T>
{
    T temp;
    if (lhs.CompareTo(rhs) > 0)
    {
        temp = lhs;
        lhs = rhs;
        rhs = temp;
    }
}
```

I see no immediate difference (unless the further generics dependency is necessary?).

FYI, the interface is pretty simple:

```
public interface IContextDependent
{
    void SetContext(MyEntities context);
}
```

And the IRepositoryProvider interface:

```
public interface IRepositoryProvider
{
    T GetRepositoryByType<T>();
}
```

What causes the error?

Comment: I've added the interface. Should my `IRepositoryProvider` inherit from `IContextDependent` than?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **RepositoryProvider**.GetRepositoryByType()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method '**IRepositoryProvider**.GetRepositoryByType()'

Your constraint on **RepositoryProvider** is: `where T : IContextDependent`
And so your constraint on **IRepositoryProvider** must *also* be `where T : IContextDependent`

That is, your interface should be written as follows:

```
public interface IRepositoryProvider
{
    T GetRepositoryByType<T>() where T : IContextDependent;
}
```